# Definition of an affine like function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

What do we call a function that is constitutes of piecewise affine functions within a known bound, and is not defined outside the bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piecewise affine partial function?  (See here for ["partial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).)